# Data Migration in chunks in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

We have lots of records in a table and we need to update all values of a column before we deploy some code. So we plan to update the table in batches, here's an example of the code (the actual chunk size is much larger). However I get `[BadMethodCallException] Method update does not exist.` inside the chunk when I run the migration. What did I do wrong?

```
class AlterContactsUpdateColumn extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::table('contacts')->chunk(100, function ($rows) {
            $rows->update(['is_valid' => true]);
        });
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a raw sql command. `UPDATE \`contacts\` SET \`is_valid\`=1 WHERE 1` and it's much much faster when you execute it inside of mysql or whatever sql you using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$rows would be a collection of 100 stdClass objects since:

1. You aren't using Eloquent.  You're using a query builder, so you won't have a model to call the update method on.
2. Chunk injects a collection, not a single instance, into your callback.

---

You could do something like this if you had an Eloquent Model named Contact:

```
    Contact::chunk(100, function ($rows) {
        $rows->each(function($contact) {
            $contact->update(['is_valid' => true]);
        });
    });
```

Or probably much more efficient, if you're just updating every contact, run one query instead of one query per contact:

```
DB::table('contacts')->update(['is_valid' => true]);
```

Comment: Thanks @devon, importing the Eloquent model is a good idea. I can't run the `update` all at once because we are actually doing it in 10,000 chunks and the actual table is so much larger and it times out every time.